# Using protected data in a parent, passed into a child class

Tags: c++, oop, class, inheritance

How can I access the data in a parent's class, which is protected, when passed into a derived class.

```
class parent
{ 
    protected:
        int a;
};

class child : public parent
{
    void addOne(parent * &);
};

void child::addOne(parent * & parentClass)
{
    parentClass->a += 1;
}

int main()
{
    parent a;
    child b;

    parent* ap = &a;

    b.addOne(ap);
}
```

Comment: Just `a += 1`. Base members become part of your class.

Comment: Please provide a code sample that actually shows what you're trying to do, and that contains no irrelevant errors (i.e. `addOne(a)` is not a valid call).

Comment: Sorry, fixed that. What I'm trying to do is edit a binary tree in a parent class, from a child class. (one parent class declared, one child class declared). The work around I have is a wrapper function in the parent that passes the binary tree head pointer to the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access protected data via a pointer/reference to the base class. This is to prevent you from breaking the invariants that other derived classes may have on that data.

```
class parent
{
    void f();
    // let's pretend parent has these invariants:
    // after f(), a shall be 0
    // a shall never be < 0.

    protected:
        int a;
};

class child : public parent
{
public:
    void addOne(parent * &);
};


class stronger_child : public parent
{
public:
    stronger_child(int new_a) {
        if(new_a > 2) a = 0;
        else a = new_a;
    }
    // this class holds a stronger invariant on a: it's not greater than 2!
    // possible functions that depend on this invariant not depicted :)
};

void child::addOne(parent * & parentClass)
{
    // parentClass could be another sibling!
    parentClass->a += 1;
}

int main()
{
    stronger_child a(2);
    child b;

    parent* ap = &a;

    b.addOne(ap); // oops! breaks stronger_child's invariants!
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't realize I could break other children this way. I redid my algorithm so that the parent class manages the data that I need, even though it doesn't quite make sense for the parent. It's better than breaking OO rules. ++Martinho

Comment: @CornSmith please check out my slight edit. I made a mistake previously. You're not restricted to the current *instance* but to pointers/references of the current *type*. A type knows its own invariants so it can manipulate other instances of that type safely (modulo bugs). For example, this works http://www.ideone.com/8LvA3

Comment: @R-Martinho-Fernandes 
So you're saying that one child class can edit another child class's parent's variables if it's the same type. Thanks for the tip! (and nice code on ideone, that was above and beyond)

Comment: Let's hope that `child` does not break `stronger_child` invariant.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean by that? Isn't that what I show in my answer?

Comment: Let's hope that <del>`child`</del> `parent` does not break `stronger_child` invariant.

Comment: @curiousguy: If `stronger_child`'s invariants are *stronger* than the `parent`'s that means that all the `parent`'s invariants *still hold*. There's no way to break anything, unless `stronger_child`'s invariants are *incompatible* with `parent`'s instead of *stronger*. And that's just bad subclassing.

Comment: But the base class `parent` does not know about the stronger invariant, so why do you expect that `parent` will not break it?

Comment: @curiousguy If the invariant is strictly *stronger*, it can't possibly break it. E.g., if `parent` said that `a` could be written the value 5, then `stronger_child` would not have a *stronger* invariant, but a *conflicting* one.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by "invariant".

Comment: Now I am 100 % sure I don't understand what you mean by "invariant".

Comment: @curiousguy Really, I mean exactly what is described on the link I posted yesterday. The invariant of a certain class is a predicate that holds true before and after every call to member functions on objects of that class. A subclass must maintain the predicate that its base class has as invariant. It may add some additional ones using logical conjunction (strengthening the invariant).

Comment: Would you admit that True is the least class invariant?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5653/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-r-martinho-fernandes)